# How to encode Map into Json in Dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, jsonexception

I am trying to convert Map<DateTime,List> into json with following code:

```
String ecoded = json.encode({
  DateTime.now(): ["Sample data", 3,true,"Example", 2],
});
```

But compiler give following error:

```
E/flutter (11773): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled 
Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:1
E/flutter (11773): #0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject 
(dart:convert/json.dart:688:7)
E/flutter (11773): #1      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn 
(dart:convert/json.dart:877:17)
E/flutter (11773): #2      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify 
(dart:convert/json.dart:862:5)
E/flutter (11773): #3      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:262:30)
E/flutter (11773): #4      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:172:45)
```

I converted many times Map into json but in all cases Map was something like that:

```
Map<String,dynamic>
```

This error is occurring because there is List

If anyone know how to convert Map<DateTime,List> into json then Answer this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Json only supports `Strings` as keys. So if you want to use `DateTimes` as keys you have to manually convert it first:

```
String ecoded = json.encode({
    DateTime.now().toString(): ["Sample data", 3,true,"Example", 2],
});
```

or

```
Map<String, dynamic> result = datetimeMap.map((k, v) => MapEntry('$k', v))
```

Answer (score 1):

In dart programming, json.encode(DateTime.Now()) which is not possible. You need to convert by using `Iso8601String()` or `toString()`

```
String ecoded = json.encode({
  DateTime.now().toIso8610String(): ["Sample data", 3,true,"Example", 2],
});
```